# capacity after TrimExcess on List<T>

Tags: c#

trim access is used minimize a collection's memory 
For example

```
 List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

If my contain 2 items after trim access capacity of list will be 2

in same manner if list contains 4 or 5 or 6 after TrimExcess capacity turns to 4 or 5 or 6 respectively

But if list contain 3  or 7 or 15 why capacity turns to 4 or 8 or 16  respectively after TrimExcess

Even after this I found one more strange behavior
if I run the following code

```
 List<int> myList = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                myList.Add(1);
                myList.TrimExcess();
                if (myList.Capacity != myList.Count())
                {
                    var different = myList.Capacity;
                }
            }
```

if statement get true only if i = 3

Can anyone please let me know the reason

Comment: list capacity c is always in c ∈ {2^x} | x ∈ N

Comment: if it is so then why in loop if count is 7 capacity is 7 after trimExcess else if count is 7 capacity is 8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the source code for `List<T>`:

```
  public void TrimExcess() {
        int threshold = (int)(((double)_items.Length) * 0.9);
        if( _size < threshold ) {
            Capacity = _size;
        }
    }
```

Where `_size` is the backing field for the `Count` property and `_items.Length` is what the `Capacity` getter returns.

So basically, `TrimExcess` only sets the capacity to `Count` if more than 10% of the array slots are not being used. That's why in some of your tests `Count` doesn't equal `Capacity`.

---

Another question from the comments:

```
   1     List<int> myList = new List<int>
   2         {
   3             1,2,3,4,5,6,7 // equivalent to calling `Add` 7 times
   4         };
   5     Console.WriteLine(myList.Capacity); // prints 8 
   6     myList.TrimExcess();
   7     Console.WriteLine(myList.Capacity); // prints 8
```

**Why does line 5 print 8?**
An empty list starts out with 0 Capacity.

- When the first element is inserted, Capacity increases to 4, its default capacity.
- When the fifth element is inserted, Capacity increases to double the current capacity. So if capacity is still 4, it goes up to 8.
- When the 9th element is inserted, Capacity is doubled again, and so on.

So, when you inserted the 5th element, capacity went from 4 to 8. If you insert two more elements, you'll see the capacity going from 8 to 16.

**Why does line 7 print 8?**

This was already answered in the first part of my answer.

Now we know why Capacity is 8 *before* calling `TrimExcess`.
And because there's less than 10% unused space* in the array, `TrimExcess` does nothing, and Capacity remains 8.

Note: Actually, there's 12.5% unused space (1 free slot / 8 possible slots in the array).
But because 7 * 0.9 is rounded to an integer, the `threshold` becomes 7. And because `7 < 7` returns false, nothing happens.

Comment: if it is so then why in loop if count is 7 capacity is 7 after trimExcess else if count is 7 capacity is 8

Comment: @slashshogdhe I'm not sure I follow your question.. Could you rephrase it? I added an example showing two use cases where (Count=7 and Capacity=7) and (Count=7 and Capacity=8).

Comment: can you please run my code and check the capacity when I = 7

Comment: List<int> myList = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                myList.Add(1);
                myList.TrimExcess();
                if (7 == myList.Count())
                {
                    var different = myList.Capacity;
                }
            }

Comment: When `i` is 7, Count and Capacity are also 7. What's so surprising?

Comment: var item = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 });
item.TrimExcess();
if u run above code the capacity will be 8????????????

Comment: @slashshogdhe I ran that code, and `item.Capacity` equals 7 on my machine.. I'm using .NET 4. Which one are you using? A previous .NET version might have a different implementation, though that would be weird..

Comment: sorry for above code can you please try this  List<int> myList = new List<int>();

            myList.Add(1);
            myList.Add(1);
            myList.Add(1);
            myList.Add(1);
            myList.Add(1);
            myList.Add(1);
            myList.Add(1);
            myList.TrimExcess();

Comment: @slashshogdhe See my updated answer, I hope it becomes clear now :)

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [msdn-Documentation on List.TrimExcess:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms132207%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The cost of reallocating and copying a large List can be considerable, however, so the TrimExcess method **does nothing** if the list is at more than **90 percent of capacity**. This avoids incurring a large reallocation cost for a relatively small gain.

This means, that in most cases your List.TrimExcess() call does nothing, and thus there is a difference between List.Count and List.Capacity

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know the reason but I decided to find out:

```
public void TrimExcess()
{
    int num = (int) (this._items.Length * 0.9);
    if (this._size < num)
    {
        this.Capacity = this._size;
    }
}
```

That was surprising to me. It only trims the capacity of the collection if more than 10% space is wasted. Seems like a clever optimization for the common case (which is developers calling `TrimExcess` when they shouldn't...).

Trim yourself:

```
list.Capacity = list.Size;
```

[It turns out this behavior is even documented.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132207%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)